# Showing a view in Navigation Controller after dismissing ZXingWidgetController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, zxing

I am having problem displaying a view in navigation controller after
dimissing ZXingWidgetController.

Here are the steps.

1. Present ZXingWidgetController modally using 
   [self presentModalViewController:widController animated:YES];
2. After scan result is returned in delegate 
   (void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController*)controller didScanResult:(NSString
   *)resultString)

dismiss ZXingWidgetController and push a view controller in navigation controller.

```
[dismiss ZXingWidgetController: [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Push a view controller in navigation controller:

```
ParsedResult *parsedResult = [[UniversalResultParser      parsedResultForString:resultString] retain];
self.result = [parsedResult retain];
self.actions = [self.result.actions retain];
ScanViewController *scanViewController = [[ScanViewController alloc]
initWithResult:parsedResult forScan:scan];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:scanViewController
animated:NO];
[scanViewController release];
```

But this results into navigation bar being hidden behind status bar
partially.

Please let me know how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try going to the `ZxingWidgetController.m` 
and changing `setStatusBarHidden` and `self.wantsFullScreenLayout` to `NO`

If that doesn't work, try adding the following to `YourAppDelegate.m`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```